# Git describe build dependency

Tags: git, build

I'm using `git describe --tags --dirty --long` to get a string which is used in my library as a `const char []` to know (e.g. by printing ) the git-revision when only having a binary of it.

I'm generating a file (gitref.c) which is compiled with all the other files. I recently realized that when I change the git revision in my clone and then rerun the build-process `gitref.c` is not re-generated. That's normal - there is no dependency.

I found out that a dependency to *.git/HEAD* is a nice start and works is most of the case. Is that dependency enough? If not, what is the right way to add a (file-)dependency?

**EDIT**: Thanks to @BenJackson: When tagging this is not enough - *HEAD* is not changed.

Comment: I don't think it would catch the case where you tag the current version and recompile (it would not change HEAD so you would not pick up the new tag name).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the only solution for this is to consider this file to always be out-of-date with a fake dependency. Every time you compile, it *must* be regenerated. A slightly more elegant solution is to always generate a `gitref.c.tmp` and then copy it over to `gitref.c` only if the files differ (e.g. on *NIX like systems you can use `cmp` to compare them byte-wise). If they are the same, just delete the temporary file.

**EDIT**: The following `Makefile` snippet works for me

```mk
PHONY: gitref_dummy
gitref_dummy:
gitref.c: gitref_dummy
    @echo "const char *gitref = \"$$(git describe --tags --dirty --long)\";" > \
        gitref.c.tmp
    @cmp -s gitref.c.tmp gitref.c || \
        (echo "Updating gitref.c"; mv gitref.c.tmp gitref.c)
    @rm -f gitref.c.tmp
```

Comment: Well, this is a possibility, but doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @PatrickB. Why not? Depending on `HEAD` is clearly not enough and unless you depend on every single file in your repository, file-dependencies are never going to solve your problem.